# Using rating bar in android

Tags: android, ratingbar

### I have a rating Bar

```
<RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/RATINGinitialvalueratingID"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RATINGseekBarID"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="5" />
```

**Say there are three stars in this .... i have two questions**

- How to show full stars all the time ?
- How to disable editing of stars    (static display of allocated
  rating)?

Comment: What does your first question exactly mean?

Comment: I am trying to display 5 stars ... rated 5 stars all the time .... and not prompting user to edit it .... hope i am clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add the following attribute to show 5 stars:

```
android:rating="5"
```

Also, try to add those to make it not editable:

```
android:isIndicator="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGinitialvalueratingID);
ratingBar.setRating(5);
ratingBar.setFocusable(false);
```