# Android ratingBar ignoring numStars

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm very new to Android development. I'm trying to add a ratingBar indicator to a layout screen that will be a ListView item, so the user sees a list of restaurant names with their star values to the right of each.

I want to limit the view to 5 stars - i.e. it should never display more than 5 stars, and 5 only if the user has rated the restaurant as 5 stars (in another activity.)

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206135/using-rating-bar-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252099/android-ratingbar), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858600/how-to-make-ratingbar-to-show-five-stars), as well as the developer.android.com documentation for ratingBar, and I cannot for the life of me get it to display *only* 5 stars.

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="64dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/restaurantNameLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Shamrock Club"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize=".01"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:rating="3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/restaurantNameLabel"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like in the Android Studio Design view; note there are 6+ stars displaying. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change from a relative layout to a linear layout this should work just fine

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="64dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/restaurantNameLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Shamrock Club"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize=".01"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:rating="3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/restaurantNameLabel"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The way it is now it will actually only show 3 stars but you can change android:rating to reflect what you would like.

Comment: Thank you! That did work. Why? Does RatingBar care what kind of layout its parent is? I didn't see anything in the documentation to indicate that.

Comment: You could also keep it as a RelativeLayout but if you want to keep it as a relatvie layout you need to remove the android:layout_alignParentRight="true" line. Between that line and the android:layout_toEndOf="@id/restaurantNameLabel" line you are stretching the RatingBar to be more stars then you want.

Comment: So the number of stars displayed is dependent on the width of the screen available, not controllable by a specific parameter? That seems kind of backwards.

Comment: I agree, it looks like there was an issue reported for something really close to this with google a while back https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3094&can=1&q=RatingBar&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened but it looks like it got closed simply because it was an old issue. You should report the issue with them so they can have a look at it when they have a chance.